# How to handle/suppress apache camel FailedToStartRouteException for S3 route on invalid aws profile

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, apache-camel

The following code works fine with a valid AWS profile, but the Spring Boot application does not start when the AWS profile is invalid or does not exist in some environments. I just want to handle or suppress the Apache camel route error, and the Spring boot application should work.

```
  @Component   
    public class AppS3RouteBuilder  extends EndpointRouteBuilder {       
    @Override     
    public void configure() throws Exception {               
    from(aws2S3("app-s3-bucket").delay(1000L)
    .useDefaultCredentialsProvider(true)
    .deleteAfterRead(true)).routeId("appS3RouteId")                       
    .log("File name:${header.CamelAwsS3Key}")                       
   .end();       
     }   
   }
```

Error Message:

```
Error starting CamelContext (camel-1) due to exception thrown: Failed to start route appS3RouteId because of null
```

Stack Trace:

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route appS3RouteId because of null
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:122)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doWarmUpRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:306)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.safelyStartRouteServices(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:189)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:147)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartCamel(AbstractCamelContext.java:2808)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartContext(AbstractCamelContext.java:2490)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStart(AbstractCamelContext.java:2445)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.SpringBootCamelContext.doStart(SpringBootCamelContext.java:43)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2081)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:313)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationCo
```